# Rails: Embed metadata in templates – YAML in my HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, metadata, yaml, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I would like to be able to set things like the page title and `<meta>` description from within HAML “pages” served up by my static page controller.

Is there a good way to do this? Ideally, I see it working something like:

1. Name files like `about_us.html.haml.yaml`
2. Use the normal `render` method
3. But now there is a hash of metadata available to my controller and layout templates, which set various headers and elements, respectively.

Thoughts?

Comment: If you want to set up title, description, noindex or similar tags in the head, then https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags is the best way to do it! I've used in a various projects, and think it's best gem ever for manipulating with title, description and other stuff that sits in the head tag.

Comment: @Dmitry, thanks, I’ll check it out. But why don’t you make your comment a full answer?

Comment: Thanks for the tip Dimitry.  Cheers!

Comment: I just though it's too easy for the full answer. May be you have other questions? :D

Comment: Hmm, well, I’d still like to be able to indirectly set HTTP headers by setting meta-data in my views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Since no one contributed a full answer)

> If you want to set up title, description, noindex or similar tags in the head, then github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags is the best way to do it! I've used in a various projects, and think it's best gem ever for manipulating with title, description and other stuff that sits in the head tag.
>
> — Dmitry Polushkin

It seems to work well for me, though it is a touch less powerful than what my question was looking for. Further answers welcome.